# Encontrar String distinta

Tags: java, archivo

Tengo miles de carpetas y dentro de cada carpeta hay archivos, con la frase 'No es información relevante', y tengo que encontrar el archivo que NO contenga esa frase, como lo puedo hacer? Gracias!

Comment: En que lenguaje? Que has intentado?

Comment: @NicolasOñate es en Java. Intenté entrar en la primera carpeta > primer fichero y copiar esa String, guardarla en una variable e ir comparando con cada fichero, pero no sale nada.

Comment: Publica el código de lo que tengas hecho, y aclara los problemas que tienes sobre el código y lo que esperas obtener. Sino es imposible darte una respuesta acertada.

Comment: Bienvenido, es demasiado importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, modifica tu pregunta en base a [ask], saludos.

Answer (score -1):

Si estás en linux puedes usar grep para buscar archivos que contengan esa palabra. En el directorio principal:

```
grep -r -v "No es información relevante"
```

Donde -r hará una búsqueda recursiva en todo el directorio y subdirectorios y -v hará la búsqueda inversa (mostrará por pantalla aquellas archivos que no contienen la cadena indicada)